# Removing loops in a list in python

Tags: python, list, loops

Hey i have one list and i want to remove loops in the list. For example, if one element is already in the list, i want to remove all elements between this element that is repeat. 
For example:

```
a=[(4,4),(5,6),(7,7),(7,6),(4,4),(8,8),(9,9)]
```

and i want to get something similiar with this:

```
a   [(4,4),(8,8),(9,9)]
```

How can i get this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the desired outcome if you have twice the same element, as in `a=[(4,4),(9,9),(5,6),(7,7),(7,6),(4,4),(8,8),(9,9)]`?

Comment: I assume you meant the duplication that is most apart? e.g., `[(4,4), (1,1), (4,4), (2, 2), (4, 4)]` would just leave `[(4,4)]`? And also, what if the "loops" intersect?

Comment: you should also have `(7,7)` in the output list

Comment: What do you do if you have overlapping ranges?

Comment: By that, I mean `[(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (1,1), (5,5), (3,3), (6,6)]`. What stays and what goes?

Comment: There are many things this example means. Please make it less ambiguous by adding more example or improving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [(4,4),(5,6),(7,7),(7,6),(4,4),(8,8),(9,9)]
b = []
for e in a:
    if e in b:
        b[b.index(e)+1:] = []
    else:
        b.append(e)

# b == [(4, 4), (8, 8), (9, 9)]
```

Comment: @Abhijit - as far as I understand the OP's example, this is what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

while True:
    loops = sorted ( ( (x [0], y [0] ) for x, y in [ (x, y) for x in enumerate (a) for y in enumerate (a) ] if x [0] < y [0] and x [1] == y [1] ), key = lambda x: x [0] - x [1])
    if loops: a = a [:loops [0] [0] ] + a [loops [0] [1]:]
    else: break
```

This should remove all loops, starting with (one of) the longest in case of intersecting (overlapping) ones.